# How to access the request object in a fetch then/response function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, request, fetch

I have a JavaScript loop iterating over an array. For every item, I perform a fetch request to insert the object. If the server response indicates it is an already inserted object, I try an update operation with another fetch call.

As the requests are asynchronous, the loop sets the request object to the next insert item before I try the update operation, so I end up requesting an update for an object it's not yet inserted.

Is there any way I can access the request object used for this fetch operation, so I can use that object instead of the loop var?

I've tried with `this` within the promise method, but it returns a reference to the window object: `console.log(this) ==> > Window http://localhost`

My code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < expectedRows; i++) {
    var row = myArray[i];
    customerCode = row['customer_code'];
    customerName = row['customer_name'];
    customerBalance = row['customer_balance'];
    // Build body call
    var callBody = {
        user: 'USER',
        code: customerCode,
        name: customerName,
        balance: customerBalance
    };
    var fetchOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        cache: "no-cache",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        redirect: "error",
        referrer: "ux-import", 
        body: JSON.stringify(callBody),
    };
    // Call
    var epurl = baseEP + '/customer/create';
    fetch(epurl, fetchOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        console.log(this) // <== Window object reference
        if (response.error === 0) {
            console.log('insert ok');
            insertRows++;
        } else {
            if (response.error == 2) {
                console.log('insert error => update');
                var updateEP = baseEP + '/customer/update';
                fetch(updateEP, fetchOptions) // <== Not what you expect 
                .then(updResponse => updResponse.json())
                .then(updResponse => {
                    if (updResponse.error === 0) {
                        console.log('update ok.')
                        updateRows++;
                    } else {
                        console.log('update error: ' + updResponse.msg)
                        errorMessages.push(updResponse.msg);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('update failure');
                    errorMessages.push(error);
                });
            } else {
                console.log('insert error.');
                errorMessages.push(response.msg);
            }
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('insert failure.');
        errorMessages.push(error);
    });
}
```

I need some way to access this fetch call request object to achieve something like this:

```
var updFetchOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    cache: "no-cache",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    redirect: "error",
    referrer: "ux-import", 
    body: this.request.body, // this as a reference to this fetch's request
}
fetch(updateEP, updFetchOptions)...
:
:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this.

```
for (let i = 0; i < expectedRows; i++) {
    let row = myArray[i];
    customerCode = row['customer_code'];
    customerName = row['customer_name'];
    customerBalance = row['customer_balance'];
    // Build body call
    let callBody = {
        user: 'USER',
        code: customerCode,
        name: customerName,
        balance: customerBalance
    };
    let fetchOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        cache: "no-cache",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        redirect: "error",
        referrer: "ux-import", 
        body: JSON.stringify(callBody),
    };
    // Call
    let epurl = baseEP + '/customer/create';
    fetch(epurl, fetchOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        console.log(this) // <== Window object reference
        if (response.error === 0) {
            console.log('insert ok');
            insertRows++;
        } else {
            if (response.error == 2) {
                console.log('insert error => update');
                let updateEP = baseEP + '/customer/update';
                fetch(updateEP, fetchOptions) // <== Not what you expect 
                .then(updResponse => updResponse.json())
                .then(updResponse => {
                    if (updResponse.error === 0) {
                        console.log('update ok.')
                        updateRows++;
                    } else {
                        console.log('update error: ' + updResponse.msg)
                        errorMessages.push(updResponse.msg);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('update failure');
                    errorMessages.push(error);
                });
            } else {
                console.log('insert error.');
                errorMessages.push(response.msg);
            }
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('insert failure.');
        errorMessages.push(error);
    });
}
```

Basically, defining variables with `var` is not a good method as it doesn't maintain its state with each iteration of loop. But using `let` maintains the variable state for each iteration and you can use the variable even after doing some async task like `fetch` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by explicitly creating the RequestInit-Object and wrapping your handler functions like this:

```
const initObject = {
    method: 'POST',
    something: 1234
};
fetch('/test.json', initObject)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(((initObject) => {
        return json => {
            console.log({json, initObject})
        }
    })(initObject));
```